# On the distance function $d(f,g) = \sup_{x\in[0,2\pi]}\{|f(x)−g(x)|\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the distance function 
$$
d(f,g) = \sup_{x\in[0,2\pi]}\{|f(x)−g(x)|\}.
$$
Let $f_n(x) = \sin(2^nx)$ where $n\in \Bbb N$: show $d(f_n,f_m)≥1$ when $n \neq m$.

I know for every $(n,m)$, the function image does show their distance is greater than 1. And when $n=0$, I can prove it.

Comment: I know for every (n,m), the function image does show their distance is greater than 1. And when n=0, I can prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n>m\ge 0$ then by letting $x=\pi/2^{m+1}\in [0,2\pi]$, we find
$$\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in[0,2\pi]}\{|\sin(2^nx)−\sin(2^m x)|\}&\geq |\sin(2^n (\pi/2^{m+1})))−\sin(2^m (\pi/2^{m+1}))|\\
&=|\sin(2^{n-m-1} \pi)−\sin(\pi/2)|=|0-1|=1.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @YaoZhao It was simpler than I thought...

Comment: Yes, this is excellent

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let me define $d_r(f,g) = sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,2 r \pi]\}$. I am going to use two properties of this distance:

- $d_r(f,g) = d(f(rx), g(rx))$.
- For $r>1$, $d_r(f,g) > d(f,g)$,    (you are taking sup over larger interval).

Since you already know how to prove for $n = 0$, without loss of generality, assume $m>n$. Then $d(f_n,f_m) = d_{2^{n}}(f_0,f_{m-n}) > d(f_0, f_{m-n}) > 1$.